# Passing address of a string to fscanf() prevented unrelated code-block from running

Tags: c, file, loops, file-io, io

I have been working on a little C program that reads in strings from a file, encrypts them using crypt() and then writes the encrypted version to a string. For some reason, I wasn't thinking and wrote the fscanf call as:

```
fscanf( filename, "%s", &string );
```

This doesn't work as strings are already represented as pointers, but this does:

```
fscanf( filename, "%s", string );
```

This logic(read,test,encrypt,print) is done in a loop. Right before the loop, I have a few lines of code that print program information to a logfile:

```
fprintf( logfile, "Called as %s\n", executable );
/* Etc... */
```

Before I realized the error with the fscanf, I noticed after the program received SIGSEGV, that the created logfile was empty. At first I tried a loop:

```
while(1)
{
  fprintf( logfile, "Looped!\n");
}
```

This worked, until I put in the read,test,encrypt,print sequence. I realize what my error is, but the question I have is:
Why would an improper reading of a string (that always segfaulted) block a completely unrelated code-block from running?

Edit: Here's the "working" code(crypt still segfaults):

```
fprintf( logfile, "Called as %s\n", executable );
fprintf( logfile, "Assigned pid %lu\n", pid );
fprintf( logfile, "Input File: %s\n", inputfilename );
fprintf( logfile, "Output File: %s\n", outputfilename );
fprintf( logfile, "Default BUFFER: %lu\n", BUFFER );
fprintf( logfile, "Crypt output sixe: %lu\n", CRYPT_OUTPUT_SIZE );
fprintf( logfile, "\n" );

/*  Try to set up space for strings */
fprintf( logfile, "Attempting to allocate %lu chars(%u) for plaintext string...\n", BUFFER,sizeof(char) );
char *plaintext_string = (char *) calloc( BUFFER, sizeof(char) );
if( plaintext_string == NULL )
{
    fprintf( logfile, "Errno %d; Error %s; Trying to allocate %lu chars(%u) for plaintext string\n",
    errno, strerror(errno), BUFFER,sizeof(char) );
    return(STRERROR);
}

fprintf( logfile, "Success; Now attempting to allocate %lu bytes for encrypted string...\n", CRYPT_OUTPUT_SIZE );
char *encrypted_string = (char *) calloc( CRYPT_OUTPUT_SIZE, sizeof(char) );
if( encrypted_string == NULL )
{
    fprintf( logfile, "Errno %d; Error %s; Trying to allocate %lu chars(%u) for encrypted string\n",
    errno, strerror(errno), (unsigned long) CRYPT_OUTPUT_SIZE, sizeof(char) );
    return(STRERROR);
}

fprintf( logfile, "\n" );

fprintf( logfile, "Entering main loop\n" );
while( TRUE )
{
    int res = fscanf( inputfile, "%s", plaintext_string );
    if( res == EOF )
    {
        fprintf( logfile, "Reached EOF in %s; Breaking from loop\n", inputfilename );
        break;
    }

    if( plaintext_string == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( logfile, "Errno %d; Error %s; String read in from %s was NULL\n", errno, strerror(errno), inputfilename);

        free(plaintext_string);
        free(encrypted_string);
        fclose(logfile);
        fclose(inputfile);

        return(STRERROR);
    }

    strcpy( encrypted_string, crypt( plaintext_string, SALT ) );
    if( encrypted_string == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( logfile, "Errno %d; Error %s; Encrypted string was NULL\n", errno, strerror(errno) );

        free(plaintext_string);
        free(encrypted_string);
        fclose(logfile);
        fclose(inputfile);

        return(STRERROR);
    }

    fprintf( outputfile, "%s\n", encrypted_string );

    /*  Clear the strings so no data is held    */
    *plaintext_string = NULL;
    *encrypted_string = NULL;
}
```

Thanks!

-- Jordan.

Comment: Post the code that is giving you trouble a [mcve].  This will save us all time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to the logfile is buffered by default. When the program crashes with a segfault, the buffer is never flushed. Either turn off buffering with `setvbuf(logfile, _IONBF);` or flush the buffer when you want it to go to the file:

```
fprintf( logfile, "Called as %s\n", executable );
fflush(logfile);
```

Comment: But that shouldn't prevent the code from being run? That's my issue. When I had the improper fscanf() call, the logprinting never ran.

Comment: Why do you think the code isn't running? It's running, and putting the output in a buffer, but the buffer is never being written to the file.